# Double array console logs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the data from 2 separate JSON feeds. When I store them in array and log it in console, it shows those two separated arrays, but when I assign each to a var, and log that var to console, the results in console are doubled. Here is the code:

```
var loadFile = function (filePath, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () { return done(this.responseText) }
    xhr.open("GET", filePath, true);
    xhr.send();
}

var myFiles = [ "link", "link" ];
var jsonData = [];

myFiles.forEach(function (file, i) {
    loadFile(file, function (responseText) {

       jsonData[i] = JSON.parse(responseText);
        console.log(jsonData[i]);

        var top50 = jsonData[0];
        console.log(top50);
}
```

Comment: It's doubled because you make a `forEach` on an array with two elements. If the array had three elements, it would be tripled.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please advise what would be the proper apporach here?

Comment: But isn't that what you want? Display the data from 2 different JSON feeds?